# How to install themes with GNOME tweak tool?

Tags: gnome, themes, appearance, gnome-tweak-tool

I have been using the default Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity for some time now and decided to start customizing it.

I have already been able to make some changes with the gnome-tweak-tool. However, there are many themes that I get from `gnome-look.org` that don't appear in the gnome-tweak-tool even after putting them in the `/usr/share/themes` folder.

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Have you placed the Themes correctly? i.e. Theme_Name>Gtk 2,3 metacity-1 folders.

Comment: i believe so. i used the command cp -rf ThemeName /usr/share/themes

Comment: Take a look at the folder, and check the folder structure is correct.

Comment: i have confirmed that i am copying the files for the right destination folder. but in /usr/share/themes, i have around 60 folders and on the gnome-tweak-tool i get very little themes

Comment: Which themes aren't working?, try moving them to your home folder see if that works.

Comment: @nunos - please add links to the themes you have downloaded to confirm that you have been trying to install GTK+3/Gnome-3 compatible themes.

Comment: @nunos If you think that my answer has responds to your issue, you can [mark it as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483) so this question remains as *answered*.

Answer (score 26):

## How to install themes in Ubuntu:

When you download a theme for Ubuntu this come compressed into a `.tar.gz` file *almost always.* What you have to do is:

1. Run the terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
2. Enter `cd ~ && mkdir .themes`
   This command will **create** a `.themes` folder in your personal folder. **The dot is necessary**
3. Enter `cp files_path ~/.themes`
   Replace `files_path` with the directory where are your zipped files. This command **copy** the compressed files into this folder.
4. Enter `cd ~/.themes && tar xvzf PACKAGENAME.tar.gz`
   Replace `PACKAGENAME` with the name of the file. This command will **unzip** the theme file into the new folder.
5. Enter `gnome-tweak-tool`

Finally will appears the **tweak** window *(similar as the following)* and you'll see the themes that you've previously copy in the themes folder and will be able to choice them!

[image: screenshoot]

*For future themes, omit the second step*

Answer (score 3):

I installed a few themes from [gnome-look.org](https://www.gnome-look.org/)

The site uses a special URL scheme. The URL handler comes in a package named `ocs-url`. Here are the [instructions for installing the URL handler on linux-apps.com](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1136805/).

However, the installation method described on this site has an issue: it marks the dependencies as manually installed.

Therefore I recommend the following method instead.

My method will ensure that, when you uninstall ocs-url, its dependencies will be automatically uninstalled as well.

First download the `ocs-url` Debian package, then (filename and directory name might differ):

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i ocs-url_3.1.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install --fix-broken
```

Once this is done, all you have to do is click on install links on gnome-look.org and them click "OK" and the themes will be installed in `~/.themes`.

Restart the Tweaks tool and your new themes should be available.

Tested on Debian.

Comment: Do I need to restart only after installing the deb file or each time I have to restart after installing new themes? Btw this works perfectly on my Ubuntu 18.4

Comment: @PratikSaluja Restarting the tweak tool was enough

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when placing themes in `/usr/share/themes`. You need to make sure the permissions are set correctly.

Right click on the folder of your theme and select properties, go to the permissions tab and set it like this:

[image: Image of Permissions]

Now go back to gnome tweak tool and your theme should be there. Alternatively, you could create `~/.theme` and put your theme in there.