# Apply theme on my Linux

Tags: themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get and install more themes, icons, and pointers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/116/how-do-i-get-and-install-more-themes-icons-and-pointers)
>   [Themes don't appear in gnome-tweak-tool](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101651/themes-dont-appear-in-gnome-tweak-tool)

I'd download a theme and I want to apply it, I'm using Linux Ubuntu 12.4 system. and every time I tried to extract it I found a massage said : You don't have the right permissions to extract archives in the folder "file:///usr/share/themes"

I'm so new in Linux, so what can I do ???

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on the folder and changing the permissions to read/write

Comment: Dear friend, I tried to but I found folder themes is disabled.. it's telling me that I'm not the owner... do you have any more ideas ??? thnx alot

Comment: @Maged See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/180526/62483) where I have described step by step how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Extract to /home/username/.themes instead (you might need to press Ctrl+H in order to reveal hidden files - that is, any file or folder whose name starts with a period).

You are trying to extract the archive to a system folder, and you need root privileges to do so. However, the alternative folder I mentioned earlier will work as well, but it just limited to your user account. If you really want to extract to /usr, run your file archiver as root using `sudo` in a terminal:

```
gksu file-roller
```

Comment: Dear friend, I don't know about sudo .. how to use it ??

Comment: Just extract to ~/.themes as I told you. There's no need in messing around with system files in this case.

Comment: If you really, really think it is better to put the files in /usr, run `gksu file-roller` from a terminal (ctrl+alt+t).