# Gnome-shell themes work with unity?

Tags: unity, gnome

Is there a way to make `gnome-shell` themes work with Unity? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must say that it doesn't, the **Gnome-shell** themes are not *entirely* compatible.

The themes that are supported by Unity are **GTK+** & **GTK2** & **GTK3**.

You can download this themes from [this place](http://linuxo.com/category/tags/gtk-3-themes), or find more in Google. After download the theme, you have to [install it](https://askubuntu.com/a/180526/62483).
e.g.:

[image: orion_theme]

There are [other themes](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/spice-up-your-desktop-with-these-5-cool.html) that you can install more easily (from the terminal).

And don't forget that you can [make your own theme for Unity](https://askubuntu.com/q/47643/62483)!

Answer (score 0):

GNOME 3 themes? Install `gnome-tweak-tool` (via USC or via `apt-get`), and change Theme->GTK+ Theme.