# Uninstalling a downloaded theme

Tags: themes, uninstall

I downloaded GnomishDark every since I applied the theme Ubuntu 12.10 hasn't been the same. I reverted to a pre-loaded theme but I think some of the dependency GnomishDark applied may be the problem.

However, whenever I go to uninstall it with `sudo apt-get remove GnomishDark` I am getting this: `E: unable to locate package GnomishDark`.

If I do `cd /usr/share/themes` and then `ls`, the theme is present and listed as GnomishDark.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Couple of points **1**, to find out what "dependency GnomishDark applied", you could explain where you got this theme from. Then someome could provide more specific advice. **2**, what you are seeing is quite odd. How are you reverting "to a pre-loaded theme"? Which OS, DE, and means of changing themes are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is normal, because *GnomishDark* is not a *package* that can be removed with the `apt-get` command.

When you [install a theme](https://askubuntu.com/a/180526/62483), you are just putting the files into the appropriate folder. So all you need to do is remove the *GnomishDark* folder (and its subfolders). You can do this as described below:

- If you have the theme in the `/usr/share/themes` directory, enter:

  `sudo rm -r /usr/share/themes/NAME_OF_THEME_FOLDER`
- If you have the theme in the `~/.themes` directory, enter:

  `sudo rm -r ~/.themes/NAME_OF_THEME_FOLDER`

`-r` is for *recursive* and tells `rm` to remove the parent folder as well as subfolders.

Comment: You have given the correct procedure for removing the theme but it's possible that OP *also* has it in `~/.themes`. If that is the case, it can be removed from there too.

Comment: I just did a clean install to resolve the problems.

Comment: @dustin A clean installation of what software? The OS or what? Have you tried my method?